# TSQL Custom Constraint - dealing with nullable foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have a requirement for the following database design.

There will be a table for all devices named DEVICE and a table for rooms named ROOM. Each Device must be assigned to either another device or a room. Currently I have a nullable foreign key relationship connection Device to Room for a field name Device.RoomId and another nullable foreign key relationship joining Device back to itself for Device.ContainerId.

Is there a more appropriate design that could be enforced through database constraints/fk relationships?  I realize that good code should be written to prevent bad data from being stored, but I'd like the added safety of db enforcement of the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds fine but, if you've not already, you could add a check constraint to ensure that exactly one of the parents is `NOT NULL`.

Consider the following pseudo-code.

```
CREATE TABLE Device (
    DeviceId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name string NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ParentDeviceId int NULL FOREIGN KEY Device (DeviceId),
    ParentRoomId int NULL FOREIGN KEY Room (RoomId),
    CHECK (
        (
            ParentDeviceId IS NULL
                AND ParentRoomId IS NOT NULL
        ) OR (
            ParentDeviceId IS NOT NULL
                AND ParentRoomId IS NULL
        )
    )
)

CREATE TABLE Room (
    Room Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name string NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```